# Javascript innerhtml not displaying on second function call undefined function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to start by saying I am a student, very new to front-end development and not really familiar with javascript, but i'm slowly trying to learn by coding some very basic stuff.

**What I am doing**

I am trying to create an odds comparison calculator, that will display the best odds for a selected match. You can [view my fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/timcoetzee/x3e96zxq/)

**Javascript**

```
   function createTeams() {
  var tour = document.getElementById('tournaments').value;
  if (tour == "six-nations") {
    var create = document.getElementById('teamsDiv').innerHTML = "<h3>Select Team</h3><select id='teams'><option value='Wales'>Wales</option><option value='England'>England</option><option value='Ireland'>Ireland</option><option value='Scotland'>Scotland</option> <option value='France'>France</option><option value='Italy'>Italy</option></select><input type='submit' value='Check Odds' onClick='checkOdds()' />"

  }
}//function createteams


function checkOdds() {
  var teams = document.getElementById('teams').value;
  //set bookmaker values
  var EngBestOdds = "<h3>Best Odds For England:</h3> Ladbrokes @ 3.00";
  var WalesBestOdds = "<h3>Best Odds For Wales:</h3> BetVictor @ 4.33";
  var IrelandBestOdds = "<h3>Best Odds For Ireland:</h3>Sportingbet @ 4.00";
  var ScotlandBestOdds = "<h3>Best Odds For Scotland:</h3>Paddy Power @ 17.00 AND BetVictor @17.00"
  var FranceBestOdds = "<h3>Best Odds For France:</h3>Sportingbet @ 6.50"
  var ItalyBestOdds = "<h3>Best Odds For Italy:</h3>BetVictor @501.00"
    //get teams
  var selectedTeam = document.getElementById("teams").value
  if (selectedTeam == "England") {
    document.getElementById("dispOdds").innerHTML = EngBestOdds;
  }
  if (selectedTeam == "Wales") {

    document.getElementById("dispOdds").innerHTML = WalesBestOdds;
  }
  if (selectedTeam == "Ireland") {

    document.getElementById("dispOdds").innerHTML = IrelandBestOdds;
  }

  if (selectedTeam == "Scotland") {

    document.getElementById("dispOdds").innerHTML = ScotlandBestOdds;
  }


  if (selectedTeam == "France") {

    document.getElementById("dispOdds").innerHTML = FranceBestOdds;
  }

  if (selectedTeam == "Italy") {

    document.getElementById("dispOdds").innerHTML = ItalyBestOdds;
  }

} //function
```

**HTML**

```
<h3>Select Tournament</h3>
<select id="tournaments">
  <option value="">-----</option>
  <option value="six-nations">Six Nations</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" onclick="createTeams()" />
<div id="teamsDiv">
</div>
<div id="dispOdds">
</div>
```

**My Problems**

1. When running this in my fiddle I get the error `undefined function
   createTeams()`
2. I feel this code is not very effective, and can be greatly improved, any tips or advice as to how I can improve this will be greatly appreciated.

**What the ultimate output should look like**

[image]

Any help and advice will be greatly appreciated

Comment: change JS settings in fiddle from `onload` to `No wrap - in head`, that should solve at least first issue

Comment: is your JS code at the top of the page? in <head>?

Comment: and for code review this is the right place http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @gurvinder372 thank you very much that solved the fiddle problem, however - I would like to improve this code, any tips will be greatly appreciated

Comment: it's working fine. results are coming as you mentioned when tested on my local pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createTeams` method is not visible in the global scope since it is enclosed in `document.ready` event handler.

You need to put this in global scope by changing the JS settings in fiddle from `onload` to `No wrap - in head`

For improving the code, you can form an object (key-value) of team-message like

```
var teamMessage = {
  "England" : "Your odds are...";
}
```

then based on the team selection, you can simply show the message like

```
document.getElementById("dispOdds").innerHTML = teamMessage[ team ];
```

Comment: Thank you for this, if I may ask, `var teamMessage = {
  "England" : "Your odds are...";
}` how do I add the other teams in this object....thank you very much

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee `var teamMessage = {
  "England" : "Your odds are...",  "NZ" : "Your odds are..."
}`

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON should help you in understanding JSON better